# select conditionally with conditional joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, sql-null

I am trying to join two tables, people and sales, and displaying results based on a where condition which should be used to join the tables.

My current attempt is showing only one result but I want all the rows in the people to be shown regardless of whether they have a record in the sales table, if they have a record and the type is credit then only I want to show amount.

```
CREATE TABLE people(
   person_id INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,name  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO people(person_id,name) VALUES (1,'John');
INSERT INTO people(person_id,name) VALUES (2,'Alice');
INSERT INTO people(person_id,name) VALUES (3,'Mary');


CREATE TABLE sales(
   sales_id INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,customer_id  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,type  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,amount  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO sales(sales_id,customer_id,type,amount) VALUES (1,1,'credit',100);
INSERT INTO sales(sales_id,customer_id,type,amount) VALUES (2,3,'cash',200);
```

Please check the [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=539dacdb66cd9f268650d5919b43d7e6) using my current code and help me get the result as shown below:

```
+---------+--------+
| name    | amount |
+---------+--------+
| john    | 100    |
| alice   | 0      |
| mary    | 0      |
+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be:

```
select p.name, coalesce(s.amount, 0) as amount
from people p
left join sales s on s.customer_id = p.person_id and s.type = 'credit'
```

The main difference with your original code is that the condition on the `left join`ed table is in the `on` side of the join rather than in the `where` clause, so it avoids filtering out people without sales.

Also note the use of table aliases, which shorten the query, and of `coalesce()` to display `0` instead of `null` for "missing" amounts.